# Make the event handler of a button click start a new event called MainPage_Loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-7, event-handling

So at the moment my page is currently working with the following code in my cs file. What I need to change is to add an event handler so that when a button is clicked the MainPage_Loaded happens only after this button is clicked.

I understand that the line

```
this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
```

is currently calling this method to start but when I try and put this code into the button1_click event handler it does not work.

```
  public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);     
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctx = new HazchemEntities(new Uri("http://devweb.compsci.chester.ac.uk/0808092/CO6009/HazchemService.svc/"));
        App.coll = new DataServiceCollection<tblChemical>(ctx);
        Lst.ItemsSource = App.coll;

        App.coll.LoadCompleted += new EventHandler<LoadCompletedEventArgs>(coll_LoadCompleted);

        var qry = "/tblChemicals?$filter UNNumber = eq'" + Search.Text + "'";
        App.coll.LoadAsync(new Uri(qry, UriKind.Relative));

        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }


   }
```

Here is the XAML code that I am using.

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Search"  Height="72" Margin="-4,0,50,0" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Button Content="Go" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="350,0,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Click="button1_Click" />

    </StackPanel>
```

What do I need to put into the button1_Click event to make it start the mainpage_loaded only when this button is clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood something... This line:

> this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);

**is not** causing the `void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` function to be called immediately. It is registering a handler for that event - when the MainPage has finished loading it internally fires the Loaded event, in turn the event handler gets called.

Setting up that handler in the `button1_Click` also makes no sense - your page has already well and truly loaded by the time a button can be clicked.

If you have some functionality in the `MainPage_Loaded` function that you want the `button1_Click` to also use then you should refactor it out into a separate function that they can both call.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the EventHandler to the MainPage Loaded event instead of to the button click.

In the constructor, try `this.button1.OnClick += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);`

Answer (score 0):

add the following code to button1_Click

```
MainPage_Loaded(sender,e);
```

Comment: It can get the job done, but is not a clean solution.